# Why no emails will get through between two users on following network setup?

Tags: networking, email, routing

I am teaching myself some networking and going through some modules but I am stuck on trying to resolve why no emails will go through the following setup. Specifically the module states that there is no email getting through between the two users. I suspect it's a port mismatch but I am not sure of my self.

[image: Image Email Network flow chart]

Answer (score 0):

**This is purely a sub netting issue by the looks of it**, which probably makes it more on topic for Networking.SE.  Unless the switch in your diagram provides some routing capabilities, then 192.168.1.2 /23 is on a different subnet than 192.168.2.0 /23.

There may be a similar subnetting error on the other side of the diagram, I didn't calculate the /29 range.

Comment: Thank you Brandyn for the quick response. The subnet makes sense now that you point it out. I posted the same question on network-engineering SE as it was the only network related SE out there and was directed here.

Answer (score 0):

John and his SonicWALL router are not on the same subnet. So John has no route to the Internet.

John is:
192.168.1.2/23.
So he’s host [xxxxxxx1.00000010] (258) on this subnet:
192.168.[0000000x.xxxxxxxx] (i.e. 192.168.0.0/23)

SonicWALL is:
192.168.2.0/23.
So it’s host [xxxxxxx0.00000000] (0) on this subnet:
192.168.[0000001x.xxxxxxxx] (i.e. 192.168.2.0/23)

Please excuse the mixed decimal/binary notation above, but I hope it gets the point across.

Comment: Thank you Spiff for your answer. As op person noted above, your subnet answer makes much sense. However, your answer gives a detailed breakdown and this was very helpful in illustrating your point. Much appreciated!